# Why is $SL_2(\mathbb F_4)\cong \operatorname{Alt}(5)$? What's wrong with my work?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-isomorphism, sylow-theory

Why is $SL_2(\mathbb F_4)\cong \operatorname{Alt}(5)$? They both have order $60$ and if a group of order $60$ has more than one Sylow $5$-subgroup, it must be $\operatorname{Alt}(5)$. But I just can't find an element in $SL_2(\mathbb F_4)$ which is of order $5$, let alone two of them! What's more, there's no element in $\operatorname{Alt}(5)$ of order $4$, $\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\\\end{pmatrix}\in SL_2(\mathbb F_4)$ is an element of order $4$. There has to be something wrong here, which I can't figure out. What's wrong here though?

Comment: Hmm. Surely
$$\pmatrix{1&1\cr0&1\cr}$$ is of order two. After all, in $\Bbb{F}_4$ we have $1+1=0$.

Comment: Wait a minute, isn't $\mathbb F_4$ the field of $4$ elements? Surely, I haven't learned much about field theory, but why is $1+1=0$ in $\mathbb F_4$?

Comment: What else could it be, @hellotinfish ? If it is not zero, then $(1+1)(1+1)=1+1+1+1=0$, so $\mathbb F_4$ wouldn't be a field.

Comment: LOL, as you can probably guess, I'm learning only the basics of group theory and don't understand what's going on. By the way, this an exercise from Abstract Algebra: Dummit & Foote where Sylow theorems are just being discussed so I really didn't know that $1+1=0$ in $\mathbb F_4$.

Comment: If you are familiar with extension fields like $\Bbb{Q}(\omega)$, where $\omega$ is a complex third root of unity, then you can similarly think of $\Bbb{F}_4$ as $\Bbb{F}_2(\omega)$. The arithmetic of that complex root of unity, when taken "carefully" modulo two gives us the rules above.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Unfortunately, no. I'm not familiar with that. I'm self-studying group theory (as some kind of preparation to university, really hope that I'll be a math student though D:), but I'm having a difficult time just to finish all these exercises about Sylow's theorem (I've worked hard for days), let alone those field theory stuff, which I probably won't get to until I enter university. What's more, the notion of a 'field' was introduced by the authors of the book just to define the general linear group... So yea...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem seems to be not knowing what the field $\Bbb{F}_4$ looks like. Most notably, you should not confuse it with the residue class ring $\Bbb{Z}/4\Bbb{Z}$. That is not a field, because the class $\overline{2}$ has no multiplicative inverse.

The field $\Bbb{F}_4$ is an extension field of $\Bbb{F}_2$, in other words
$\Bbb{F}_2\subset \Bbb{F}_4$ in such a way that both addition and multiplication are extended. This extension field can simply be described as

$$\Bbb{F}_4=\{0,1,\omega,\omega+1\},$$ where the arithmetic is determined by the obvious properties of $0$ and $1$, and the relations $1+1=0$ and $\omega^2=\omega+1$ (consequently $\omega^3=1$). If you are familiar with the method of constructing extension fields as quotient rings of the ring of polynomials over the base field, then you can use
$$\Bbb{F}_4\simeq\Bbb{F}_2[x]/\langle x^2+x+1\rangle,$$ where the isomorphism sends $\omega\mapsto x+\langle x^2+x+1\rangle$. Here it is crucial that $x^2+x+1$ is an irreducible polynomial in $\Bbb{F}_2[x]$.

With these misunderstanding out of the way you can quickly verify that the set of matrices of the form
$$
\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&x\\0&1\end{array}\right)
$$
with $x$ ranging over $\Bbb{F}_4$ gives you a Sylow 2-subgroup isomorphic to the Klein 4-group. All the matrices of this form commute with each other, and have squares equal to $I_2$.

On the other hand, the matrix
$$
B=\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&1\\1&\omega\end{array}\right)
$$
can be shown to be of order five (check it to gain familiarity with the arithmetic of $\Bbb{F}_4$!). I constructed it as a companion matrix of the polynomial
$$
p(x)=x^2+\omega x+1\in\Bbb{F}_4[x].
$$
If $\alpha$ is a zero of $p(x)$, we can check, repeatedly using the fact $p(\alpha)=0$, that
$$
\begin{aligned}
\alpha^2&=\omega\alpha+1,\\
\alpha^3&=\alpha\alpha^2=\omega\alpha^2+\alpha=(\omega^2+1)\alpha+\omega=\omega\alpha+\omega,\\
\alpha^4&=\alpha\alpha^3=\omega\alpha^2+\omega\alpha=(\omega+\omega^2)\alpha+\omega=\alpha+\omega,\\
\alpha^5&=\alpha\alpha^4=\alpha^2+\omega\alpha=1.
\end{aligned}
$$
So the zeros of $p(x)$ are two elements of order five in an extension field of $\Bbb{F}_4$.

Comment: So $\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&\omega\\\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}1&\omega\\\omega&\omega\\\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}\omega&\omega\\\omega&1\\\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}\omega&1\\1&0\\\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\\\end{pmatrix}$
are all the powers of $\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&\omega\\\end{pmatrix}$, right?

Comment: Correct, @hellotinfish. Well done!

Comment: $$
\det \left( \begin{matrix}
 0&  1\\
 1&  \omega\\
\end{matrix} \right) =-1\ne 1,
$$
it's not a matrix in $SL_2(F_4)$.

Comment: @atlantic0cean In $\Bbb{F}_4$ we have $-1=1$. It is a characteristic two field.

Comment: Thank you, I get it!