# Number of elements in $SL_2(GF(2^2))$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $SL_2(GF(2^2))$ be the special linear group with coefficients in $GF(2^2)$, *i.e.*, $GF(2^2) = \{0,1,a,a+1\}$. My lecturer concluded that this group contained $60$ elements, or in general $p^n((p^n)^2 - 1)$, in this case $2^2(2^4 - 1) = 4 \cdot 15 = 60$.

I am wondering why this is the case, one can obviously write up all possible and count to $60$, but that seems a bit troublesome. And what about bigger matrices? $SL_3$ for instance.

Comment: Connected : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2340644/305862

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way to count the number of elements in $SL_2(GF(q))$ is to count the number of elements of $GL_2(GF(q))$ and then use the fact that the homomorphism
$$\det:GL_n(GF(q))\rightarrow GF(q)^{\times}$$
is surjective. The first isomorphism theorem tells you that since $\ker(\det)=SL_n(GF(q))$ then $GL_n(GF(q))/SL_n(GF(q))\simeq GF(q)^{\times}$ and thus
$$|SL_n(GF(q))|=\frac{|GL_n(GF(q))|}{q-1}.$$
In the case $n=2$ to get a matrix in $GL_n(GF(q))$ we first choose a nonzero vector for the first column, so $q^2-1$ choices, and then a second nonzero vector that is not a multiple of the first, so $q^2-1-(q-1)=q^2-q$ choices. So the number of elements in $GL_2(GF(q))$ is $(q^2-1)q(q-1)$ and then $|SL_2(GF(q))|=(q^2-1)q$, and when $q=4$ you have $60$ elements.

To generalise to the case $n=3,4,\dots$ the only thing you need to do is continue our counting argument for the number of elements in $GL_n(GF(q))$.